# Обход капчи google

Tags: javascript, c#, html, captcha

Здравствуйте.

Задача, как я думаю, попадалась многим, но вот у меня возникла с ней проблема. Необходимо обойти капчу гугла. Я пробовал парсить ссылку наподобие этой:

> https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6Ld8RcESAAAAAEo6_M9BjluesU7nWtdKmhIeU-jD

Брал оттуда поле `challenge`, и в итоге получалась ссылка на изображение капчи, при переходе на которую загружалось изображение, отличное от того, которое было на форме заполнения этой самой капчи.

> https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c=03AHJ_Vuvd4355JF1_Up26FnRQ-ZzXI2brUexqfmDfeSuM2suiANMkKI35eK8zH90lDiunUcwXjmK9pXL0ctU5nnhvPkoQq6KdRj7NFJ4gOoXfQucViu_HeJlhiFbn83xzYcyXAJv7r6v6MaUvLIh6hn8OjJyEzKxYGMdGvSLjj2VmK3Nh9-nWrGUzgCr8t2XIsAXvqj9OUJLXYRi9ZXz73SKRTSoo5jTDpA

Причем на изображении нужно было угадать уже 2 слова.
Далее я попробовал вытащить из кода страницы через webbrowser URL капчи, которая отображается на странице. Заглохло все на том, что webbrowser не видит `recaptcha_challenge_image`, по которому я хотел получить атрибут `src`.

```
<div id="recaptcha_image"
style="width: 300px; height:
57px;"><img
id="recaptcha_challenge_image"
alt="Проверка по слову reCAPTCHA"
height="57" width="300"
src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c=03AHJ_VuuNAPsln1Jmd_wBVEquVj_BF_96uG6QfKdv........."></div>
```

Comment: А не пробовал вот это 03AHJ_Vuvd4355JF1_Up26FnRQ-ZzXI2brUexqfmDfeSuM2suiANMkKI35eK8zH90lDiunUcwXjmK9pXL0ctU5nnhvPkoQq6KdRj7NFJ4gOoXfQucViu_HeJlhiFbn83xzYcyXAJv7r6v6MaUvLIh6hn8OjJyEzKxYGMdGvSLjj2VmK3Nh9-nWrGUzgCr8t2XIsAXvqj9OUJLXYRi9ZXz73SKRTSoo5jTDpA
подставлять в g-recaptcha-response ?? меня очень тоже интересует обход сей защиты
скайпмойvostario

Answer (score 2):

Никогда не приходилось копаться там...
Одно ясно точно - одно обращение выдаёт одну (в идеале - уникальную) капчу. И каждый раз разную.
Т.е. если хочешь получить текущий URI, то проще запросить весь код, спарсить оттуда значения и запросить по ним капчу - она будет валидна.
Один запрос от тебя сгенерирует капчу и один ответ от тебя её же разгадает.
Так работают обычные сайты, гугл, конечно, может выпендриться, но не на много, думаю.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте так чтобы изображения грузилось один раз а потом уже отправлялось через API на сервисы разпознавания каптчи.